# How to use dot as decimal separator when the current culture is Greek

Tags: blazor, decimal, cultureinfo, separator

I would like to change the decimal separator in a Blazor .NET 7 multi-language site when the selected language is Greek.

The numbers are by default changed to comma separated when I change the language to Greek and this cause me troubles in calculations in multiple places of my code.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the NumberDecimalSeparator according to your needs. Assuming you want a dot :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    ...        
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    ...
}
```

Note that i tested only for blazor server i am not sure if it works for wasm too.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal doesn't came with dot or comma, but when convert to string, it will add dot or comma depending on thread culture.
You can add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when comvert.

```
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
            decimal d = 5.50m;
            string withComma = d.ToString();
            string withDot = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(withComma);
            Console.WriteLine(withDot);
```

output
[image]